# How to retrieve data under unique key?

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-realtime-database

I want to retrieve the values under location in listview.
S2.2,S3.3,S4.2 will be displayed in a listview. How can I access data under a unique key?

[image]

**How i declare my firebase**

```
      databaseURL: "https://trackkit-a5cf3-default-rtdb.asia-southeast1.firebasedatabase.app").reference();


  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(

  body: Column(
    children: <Widget>[
      StreamBuilder(
        stream: database.onValue,
        builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<Event> snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData && !snapshot.hasError &&
              snapshot.data!.snapshot.value != null) {
            print("Error on the way");
            lists.clear();
            DataSnapshot dataValues = snapshot.data!.snapshot;
            Map<dynamic, dynamic> values = dataValues.value;
            values.forEach((key, values) {
              lists.add(values);
            });
            return  ListView.builder(
              shrinkWrap: true,
              itemCount: lists.length,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                return Card(
                  child: ListTile(
                    title: Text("Location: " + lists[index]["Location"].toString()),
                    leading: const SizedBox(
                    width: 50,
                    height: 50,
                  ),
                  ),
                );
              },
            );
          }
          return const Text("Add Kits");
        },
      ),
      ElevatedButton(
        child: const Text('Add Kits'),
        onPressed: () {
          Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const AddKit()),
          );
        },
      ),
    ],

  ),

);
```

}

**How i push the unique key**

```
 ElevatedButton(
        child: const Text('Save'),
        onPressed: () async  {
          final DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase(databaseURL: "https://trackkit-a5cf3-default-rtdb.asia-southeast1.firebasedatabase.app").reference().child('NTU');
          DatabaseReference newreference = reference.push();
          await newreference.set({'Location': (location.text)});
        },
      ),
```

How do I retrieve the data under a unique key? Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: How is `database` in the first snippet initialized?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Hi, I mean how I call the database!